# Vim: how to align a line onder the cursor as the first line of the page

Tags: vim

***Just wanted to share in case anyone needs to do what i needed.***

**case**:

Imagine you're on the first line of a function and want to see its content.
By moving that line on the top of the page, you could see its body!

> I'm wondering if someone else has another way!

Answer (score 7):

`zt` scrolls your view so that the current line is at the top of your screen.

See `:help scroll-cursor` for more.

Comment: Very nice and clever!

Comment: @HasanSh I also often use `L` and `H` to move my cursor to the very lowest / highest line on the screen.

From there, a `zz` will put the line your cursor is in the middle of the screen.
`zt` puts the line at the top of the screen. `zb` puts the line at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: These keystrokes indeed are very valuable! thanks for sharing:)

Comment: If you are at any place that has a call to that function (with the cursor over its name) you can split the window with `Ctrl-w-s` and go to its definition by typing `gd`.  Another way is place the cursor over the function name, type `gd` to go to its definition see, copy,  or change what you need and get back to where you was by typing `Ctrl-o`.

Answer (score 0):

**solution**:

With a new keystrokes you can achieve that:

- `zz`; your line as the center of the page.
- `<shift>l`; move the cursor to the end of the page.
- `<shift>h`; move the cursor to the beginning of the page.

And you have your cursor and desired line at the first line of the page.